# Lowe´s Yahalom Security Protocol

Tags: security

Is there any known attack on this modified version of Yahalom? Cannot find anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some papers on attacks concerning a multi-protocol environment. For example, see [here](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.inf.ethz.ch%2Fcremersc%2Fdownloads%2Fdownload.php%3Ffile%3Dtechreports%2FVerification%2520of%2520multi-protocol%2520attacks%2520Techreport.pdf&ei=wriTS8qUIaOCmwPC7tzaBg&usg=AFQjCNFZ_kszegdxKsQgqT9ctVdOyIqSGQ&sig2=ZQ9cRYt9iuxm8y1him1cLg).

Comment: So there´s no attack on isolated (Lowe Yahalom only) protokol? Am I right?

Comment: Well, Google didn't find anything that implies that, on the first 20-something results, and I've tried several search strings. However, that has none to say that an attack doesn't exist or will exist in the future: it merely suggests that there is no widely-known or published attack. You can never know what people or agencies don't publish (maybe the NSA has found an attack and won't publish the results?). You can analyze Lowe's original paper yourself: http://web.comlab.ox.ac.uk/oucl/work/gavin.lowe/Security/Papers/completeness.ps